# Ambiente para testes banco de dados Android

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, android-studio

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo simples com Android Studio, utilizando Java como linguagem.
Atualmente, estou implementando a rotina de login e logout e estou com algumas duvidas.
1° ) Ha necessidade de eu utilizar algum SGBD local escrito em SQL para acessar localmente os usuários cadastrados para que o aplicativo simule o ato de login? Todos os dados seriam​ fictícios, apenas para testes locais e validar erros de acesso ou sintaxe de código. Poderiam me recomendar um  com melhor desempenho?
2° ) Após realizar os testes, como devo proceder em termos de disponibilizar a base de dados para ser acessada via Web services? Posso utilizar o mesmo banco criado anteriormente ou devo criar um utilizando outra tecnologia?

Nao estou muito por dentro do funcionamento destas logísticas de acesso à bancos com Android, por isso, minhas perguntas podem suar meio sem sentido.
Estou utilizando SO Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1° ) Ha necessidade de eu utilizar algum SGBD local escrito em SQL para acessar localmente os usuários cadastrados para que o aplicativo simule o ato de login?

O Android trabalha com banco de dados SQLite (há alternativas NoSQL), que é local, e tem também o SharedPreferences para salvar dados simples. O SharedPreferences armazena apenas um conjunto de chave-valor.

> Todos os dados seriam​ fictícios, apenas para testes locais e validar erros de acesso ou sintaxe de código. Poderiam me recomendar um com melhor desempenho?

Da uma analisada se o Firebase atende à sua necessidade:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?hl=pt-br

> 2° ) Após realizar os testes, como devo proceder em termos de disponibilizar a base de dados para ser acessada via Web services? Posso utilizar o mesmo banco criado anteriormente ou devo criar um utilizando outra tecnologia?

O banco de dados nativo do Android (SQLite) trabalha apenas com dados locais, como já mencionei anteriormente, não sendo possível a conexão remota. Nesse caso, para trabalhar com dados remotos, é necessário que crie um webservice  e consuma os dados, armazenando-os localmente. Bibliotecas como Retrofit e Jersey ajudam nessa implementação:

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

https://github.com/jersey/jersey

Não sei se é bem isso que você queria, mas deve ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! 
Vou fazer os testes e pesquisar a respeito do FireBase.